# Find m so that the equation has integer solutions

Tags: roots, quadratics

We are given the following equation: $(m+1)x^2-(2m+1)x-2m=0$, where $m\neq-1$.

We have to find all integers $m$ so that the equation above has integer solutions.

I know that $m=0$ and $m=-2$ satisfy the conditions, but is there a way to find $m$ without trying random values, as I did?

Comment: $$(2m+1)^2+8m(m+1)=12m^2+12m+1=3(2m+1)^2-2=n^2$$  $$\implies3(2m+1)^2-n^2=3-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Z$ be the solutions of $(m+1)x^2-(2m+1)x-2m=0$.

Then, by Vieta's formula,
$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{-(2m+1)}{m+1}=2-\frac{1}{m+1}$$
Now $\frac{1}{m+1}$ has to be an integer, so $m+1=\pm 1\implies m=0,-2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a very nice solution!